# How to callback an Activity in onAttach with Otto?

Tags: android, callback, navigation-drawer, dagger, otto

I am working on an app which uses the [NavigationDrawer](https://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation-drawer.html). Different fragments are placed into the content view of the `MainActivity` whenever a menu item in the drawer is selected.
To inform the `MainActivity` that a `Fragment` successfully attached the following callback is executed:

```
public class CustomFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        ((MainActivity) activity).onSectionAttached();
    }

}
```

Since I am started using [*Otto*](http://square.github.io/otto/) with [*Dagger*](http://square.github.io/dagger/) in the project I am curious how I can substitute the callback with a `.post()` event such as:

```
mBus.post(new CustomFragmentAttachedEvent);
```

The problem is that `mBus` is `null` in `onAttach()`. It gets initialized in `onCreate()`.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ((MyApp) getActivity().getApplication()).getObjectGraph().inject(this);
}
```

Here is an [example of such a Fragment class](http://pastebin.com/VUfS6Pih).

References:

- [Complete Android Fragment & Activity Lifecycle](https://github.com/xxv/android-lifecycle)

---

You can easily try out the example yourself: Create a new project from the **`NavigationDrawer` template available in Android Studio**, add *Dagger* and *Otto* and try to substitute the mentioned callback.

---

Working solution:

- Here is the [example Fragment](http://pastebin.com/ZN26ud9X) in the final working version.

Comment: I can't help, but I am just wondering why you can't create the reference to mBus in the activity onCreate or in the onInflate of the fragment.  Again, just curious.

Comment: @nPn I am just following [what Jake Wharton told (slide 141)](https://speakerdeck.com/jakewharton/android-apps-with-dagger): inject in `onCreate()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a provider for your `Otto` bus with `Dagger` as follows:

```
@Module(injects = {
    YourFragment.class, 
    MainActivity.class
},complete = true)    
public class EventBusModule {

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    Bus provideBus() {
        return new Bus();
    }
}
```

Then you register the `EventBusModule` when you create your `ObjectGraph`. You can create your graph in the `Application`'s `onCreate()`:

```
public class MyApplication extends Application{

    public void onCreate() {
        Object[] modules = new Object[]{new EventBusModule()};
        Injector.init(modules);
    }

}
```

You would need to create an `Injector` that has some static methods and a reference to the `ObjectGraph` so you can manipulate it without having a reference to the `Application`. Something like this:

```
public final class Injector {

    private static ObjectGraph objectGraph = null;

    public static void init(final Object... modules) {

        if (objectGraph == null) {
            objectGraph = ObjectGraph.create(modules);
        }
        else {
            objectGraph = objectGraph.plus(modules);
        }

        // Inject statics
        objectGraph.injectStatics();
    }

    public static final void inject(final Object target) {
        objectGraph.inject(target);
    }

    public static <T> T resolve(Class<T> type) {
        return objectGraph.get(type);
    }
}
```

Then you just use `@Inject` in your `Fragment` to let `Dagger` give you a `Bus` instance and inject the `Fragment`:

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment{

    @Inject Bus mBus;

    public void onAttach(){
        Injector.inject(this);
    } 

}
```

Comment: You misunderstood the question. The integration of Otto is not the problem. It already works in general.

Comment: I am not sure I understand: Do you suggest I can omit `((MyApp) getActivity().getApplication()).getObjectGraph().inject(this);` in all fragments assuming that I put `@Inject Bus mBus;` in each fragment? Please extend your answer to clarify.

Comment: Yes, you can avoid that line if you `@Inject` the `Bus` on a `Application` class and call `ObjectGraph.inject(this) on it. This works because as soon as you make that call, Dagger will have a reference of a `Bus` to use anywhere in your app. We can chat if this still doesn't make sense.